# Pascal - "flickering" when moving between 2 "buttons" in CMD

Tags: pascal

today I have been trying to start with my school work ,I´ve begun with some little graphic ,specifically with menu ,where there is 7 titles and you can move between 2 of them with Key-Up and Key-Down . The main issue is when you are moving fastly,you can see I would call that "flickering" ,because it's not fast enough to redraw it.Here is the main idea of this.How can I solve this out? I would like to have it as they have it f.e. in Free Pascal IDE..picture down`

```
procedure nakresliHviezdy(str:string;surX,surY:byte;backgroundCol:byte);

var i,j:byte;
    sirkaRamcek,vyskaRamcek:byte;
    dlzkaSlova:byte;
begin
  TextBackground(backgroundCol);
  sirkaRamcek:=40;
  vyskaRamcek:=3;
  dlzkaSlova:=length(str);
  for i:=1 to sirkaRamcek do begin
    for j:=1 to vyskaRamcek do begin
      gotoxy(i+surX,j+surY);
      if ((i=sirkaRamcek) or (i=1) or (j=1) or (j=vyskaRamcek)) then write(' ');
      if ((j=2) and ((i<(sirkaRamcek-dlzkaSlova) DIV 2 +1)) or (i>(sirkaRamcek-dlzkaSlova) DIV 2  + dlzkaSlova)) then write(' ');
      if ((i=(sirkaRamcek-dlzkaSlova) DIV 2 +1) and (j=2)) then writeln(str) ;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure menu;
var pocitadlo:integer;
    klavesa:char;
    farba1,farba2,farba3,farba4,farba5,farba6,farba7:byte;
    suradnicaX,suradnicaY:byte;
begin
  pocitadlo:=1;

  cursoroff;
  TextColor(yellow);
  suradnicaX:=40;
  suradnicaY:=1;
  nakresliHviezdy( '1.Vlozit vozidlo do evidencie STK',40,1,4);
  nakresliHviezdy( '2.Najst vozidlo v evidencii STK',40,5,1);
  nakresliHviezdy( '3.Opravit udaje o vozidle',40,9,1);
  nakresliHviezdy( '4.Vymazat vozidlo z evidencie',40,13,1);
  nakresliHviezdy( '5.Zoznam vsetkych vozidiel',40,17,1);
  nakresliHviezdy( '6.Zoznam nesposobilych vozidiel',40,21,1);
  nakresliHviezdy( '7.Koniec programu',40,25,1);
  while True do begin
  klavesa:=ReadKey;
  if klavesa=#72 then dec(pocitadlo);
  if klavesa=#80 then inc (pocitadlo);
  if (pocitadlo=0) then pocitadlo:=1;
  if (pocitadlo=8) then pocitadlo:=7;
  if ((klavesa=#13) and (pocitadlo=7)) then exit;


  case pocitadlo of
       1:begin nakresliHviezdy( '1.Vlozit vozidlo do evidencie STK',40,1,4);nakresliHviezdy( '2.Najst vozidlo v evidencii STK',40,5,1); end;
       2:begin nakresliHviezdy( '1.Vlozit vozidlo do evidencie STK',40,1,1);nakresliHviezdy( '2.Najst vozidlo v evidencii STK',40,5,4);  nakresliHviezdy( '3.Opravit udaje o vozidle',40,9,1); end;
       3:begin nakresliHviezdy( '2.Najst vozidlo v evidencii STK',40,5,1);nakresliHviezdy( '3.Opravit udaje o vozidle',40,9,4);nakresliHviezdy( '4.Vymazat vozidlo z evidencie',40,13,1); end;
       4:begin  nakresliHviezdy( '3.Opravit udaje o vozidle',40,9,1);nakresliHviezdy( '5.Zoznam vsetkych vozidiel',40,17,1); nakresliHviezdy( '4.Vymazat vozidlo z evidencie',40,13,4);  end;
       5:begin nakresliHviezdy( '4.Vymazat vozidlo z evidencie',40,13,1); nakresliHviezdy( '6.Zoznam nesposobilych vozidiel',40,21,1);nakresliHviezdy( '5.Zoznam vsetkych vozidiel',40,17,4);  end;
       6:begin  nakresliHviezdy( '5.Zoznam vsetkych vozidiel',40,17,1); nakresliHviezdy( '7.Koniec programu',40,25,1); nakresliHviezdy( '6.Zoznam nesposobilych vozidiel',40,21,4); end;
       7:begin nakresliHviezdy( '6.Zoznam nesposobilych vozidiel',40,21,1); nakresliHviezdy( '7.Koniec programu',40,25,4);    end;
  end;
  end;
end;`
```

[Here you can see how my program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOZa1.png)

[Free Pascal IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhA6b.png)
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The textmode IDE uses the Free Vision framework that uses the video unit for video abstraction. The video unit maintains a virtual screen and only writes the changed parts to the screen. Both FV and the video unit come with FPC.

Start by looking at the Lister demo, in the FPC demoes that shows how to use unit video directly.